# Why are some Microsoft languages called "visual"? (Visual C#, Visual Basic .NET, Visual C++)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net

I understand visual programming languages to be those languages that allow the programmer to to manipulate graphical--rather than textual--objects onscreen to build functionality.

The closest thing I see in C#, VB, etc. is RAD controls, but that is just composing UI and the very simplest functionality -- it has nothing to do with the language itself, even.

Why, then is C# called "Visual C#", Basic .NET called "Visual Basic .NET," etc.?
What is "visual," or what is the rationale or history behind the nomenclature?

Comment: THis seems to come from the microsoft marketing team. Visual basic originally referred to the UI-oriented style of programming. When that turned out to sell well, Microsoft branded other products the same way.

Apparently, Microsoft loves to cross brand things. Remember .NET messenger?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a marketing question for elsewhere?

Comment: Just realized - "Visual C++" is not a CLR language (though there's a CLR version of it). Updated title and tags.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think it has to do with the languages themselves being "visual."

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C_Sharp):

> The term Visual denotes a brand-name relationship with other Microsoft programming languages such as Visual Basic, Visual FoxPro, Visual J# and Visual C++. All of these products are packaged with a graphical IDE and support rapid application development of Windows-based applications.

Answer (score 12):

The languages are not called "Visual". The products are "Visual".

This is from way back before .NET. "Visual" Basic was "Visual" because of the forms development GUI. "Visual" C++ was "Visual" because of MFC and the wizards for creating an MFC application.

Comment: At least for VB, the language *is* called 'Visual' : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050%28VS.71%29.aspx "This document describes the Visual Basic .NET language" - it is its own dialect of BASIC, distinct from (say) QBASIC

Comment: The original language is Visual Basic. There were versions 1-6 before Visual Basic.NET. VB was a COM-based rapid application development product, primarily for the development of forms-based applications (similar to Windows Forms).

Answer (score 7):

I suspect it all dates back to the original [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_(classic)#History). The "visual" part of this was the UI designer...

> The Ruby interface generator provided the "visual" part of Visual Basic

Answer (score 7):

The use of the work "Visual" started to get popular with the introduction of [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) version 1.0; it was the first version that ran natively inside Windows, whereas other versions ran in DOS mode even though they were able to produce Windows-runnable code. It has nothing to do with the languages, rather with the environment where the IDE runs.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is mainly a marketing choice.

It could, however be related to the fact that "Visual Studio" is a GUI, thus a way to "visualize" your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's all going from some event or some product name choice. And now, it just about the brand.

I mean, like, nowadays you can't even think about some IDE called `Studio` and the same can be said about, for example, `Visual Eclipse`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your second paragraph. Why can't I think about those things?

Comment: Never mind. What I was trying to same is that, for example `Coca-cola` wouldn't definitely change it's name to something else.